# html5 finalize application phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have build an application for android using phonegap and I need to ask a question about how to finalize the app one you leave it by presssing the home button of your android device. I have tried with the finalize() method from java, but I do not know where to place it in my code. Sorry about this very general question.

Thank you

Comment: You don't finalize. Apps just keep sitting idle in memory until Android decides it does not want them any more and kills them.

Comment: Hi Zapl, thanks for the prompt reply. The issue is that my app checks location using the GPS,  and every time I exit the app, the device keeps checking for the GPS coordinates, thus wasting battery in unnecessary GPS checks.... Any ideas on how to shut down the app after a certain time of inactivity? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put function in your body: onunload="yourfunction()".

When you exit your application OS puts your app in "pause" state before it kill it. You can set  a listener for this: document.addEventListener("pause", yourfunction, false);

Hope it work for you.